# Editor tool to link to BoardGameGeek

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, formatting

Can we have a special Link button in the editor to make links to BoardGameGeek?

I see I should have explained it a little more... What I'm looking for is a button where you just have to enter the name of the game and it creates a link to bgg.

- One option would be to just have it link to the search results for that name.
- A more elaborate goal would be to fetch the list returned by the search and let the user choose a game to link to.

I am aware that you can use the normal link tool for this but I think it would be more convenient this way. Similarly like MtG.SE has a way to easily link cards...

Comment: What would this get you vs. using the normal link button?

Comment: @Kristo: I've elaborated the idea to make it more clear...

Answer (score 7):

After a year of waiting, I'm going to [status-decline](/questions/tagged/status-decline) this. I don't believe a *majority* of questions on this site would be improved by having this functionality added, and I believe the technical limitations of BGG depreciate the value of this even further. Feel free to reopen this discussion if you feel strongly about it, but I personally don't see the merit in it. Better luck next time. :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to disagree here, for two reasons:

1. Board game titles are not unique.  One would have to know how BGG names certain games (and their expansions!) to get the link to work.  That's at least as much work on the user's part as a normal link.
2. [BoardGameGeek is not necessarily the canonical source for game info](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257/provide-links-to-bgg-wikipedia-or-the-official-game-page/259#259).

It's a nice idea in theory, but I just don't think it buys you enough over a standard link to ask the SE people to implement it for us.

Comment: I already expressed my view in that thread that I think BGG is most likely to provide a good first overview for any given game.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be a great idea, since I'm always having to open up another page to get the BGG link.  We would definitely need the list to choose from though.